# Python3.6にアップデートしたら、Python2.7で使えてたものが動作しなくなった

Tags: python, python3, sympy, mathjax

Pythonのsympyモジュールのsympy.printing.mathmlを使用しています。

Python3.6で、以下のtest1.pyを実行すると、エラーが起きてしまいます。

**test1.py**

```
import sys, json
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml

print(mathml(1/6))
```

**test1.pyの実行結果(エラーの内容)**

```
$ python test1.py

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test1.py", line 5, in <module>
        print(mathml("1/6"))
      File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/printing/mathml.py", line 1906, in mathml
        return MathMLContentPrinter(settings).doprint(expr)
      File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/printing/mathml.py", line 68, in doprint
        unistr = mathML.toxml()
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toxml'
```

test2.pyのように分数のない単純な状態で実行すると、Python3.6でもエラーは起きません。

**test2.py**

```
import sys, json
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml

print(mathml(1))
```

Python2.7を使用していた時には、このようなエラーがありませんでした。Python3.6に切り替えてから起こるようになりました。
分数表記に限らず、全体的にPython3.6ではsympy.printing.mathmlでエラーが起きるようになっている気がします。
何が原因で、どうすればエラーなく実行できるようになりますでしょうか？

Sympyのバージョンは1.4です。
Windows10にVirtualBoxとVagrantをインストールし、Ubuntuの仮想環境を構築して開発しています。Ubuntuのバージョンが14だったのが問題かと思い、16.04.6 LTSにアップデートしてみましたが関係なくエラーが出続けています。

Comment: `from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml; print(mathml(1/6))` というコードで再現しました。（Python 3.7.3、sympy==1.4）

Comment: Python3.7.3で動くということは、Python3の問題というわけではなさそうですかね？こちらもSympyのバージョンを確認したところ1.4でした。

Comment: バグが再現したということです、分かりづらくすみません。回答が集まらなかったらsympyの方にIssueを立てると良いかもしれません。

Comment: Python 3.6へのアップデート方法や使い方を工夫したら良いのでは？ [pythonのデフォルトバージョンを3.7にしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53587/26370) の記事が参考になるかも。私の回答は-1が付いてるのでやめておいた方がよいですが、解決マークの付いた@cubickさんの方法とか、@suzukisさんの方法を参考に、ubuntuに読み替えて試してみてください。

Comment: `print(mathml(S("1/6")))` としてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: print(mathml(S("1/6")))とすると、NameError: name 'S' is not definedと表示されました。

Comment: それでは `print_mathml("1/6")` ではどうなりますか？

Comment: NameError: name 'print_mathml' is not definedとなりました。

Comment: こちらの環境は python 3.7.3, sympy 1.4 ですが、`print(mathml(S("1/6")))` を実行すると `<apply><divide/><cn>1</cn><cn>6</cn></apply>` と表示されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。実行結果は求めているものと一致していますが、Sというのはどういった処理を行うものでしょうか？ライブラリ等の機能ではなくPythonに標準で付いている機能でしょうか？

Comment: `S` というのは `sympify`関数のエイリアスになります(文字列の式をsympy のオブジェクトとして生成します)。ですので、`print(mathml(sympify("1/6")))` と同義になります。これで `NameError` が発生するとすれば、そちらでインストールされている sympy パッケージに何らかの問題があるのかもしれません。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94341/discussion-between-pekochun-and-metropolis)しましょう。

Comment: PicoSushiさんから頂いたコメントを見て、この実行内容だけであれば、sympyのimport文が不要だと思い、test1.pyからfrom sympy import *
の記述を削除してしまっていました。sympyのimport文を元に戻すと、print(mathml(S("1/6")))で正しく出力されるようになりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメント欄で教えて頂いた内容で

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml

print(mathml(sympify("1/6")))
```

とすると、通りました。