# sympifyで大文字の"S"を数式に変換するには (Python Sympy)

Tags: python, sympy, mathjax

文字列から、MathMLのコードを生成するプログラム**test001.py**
を書いています。

**test001.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml

def returnMathML(value):
    str = "<math>"
    if '=' in value:#文字列中に=(イコール)が含まれている場合
        str += mathml(Eq(*map(sympify, value.split('='))),printer='presentation')
    else:
        str += mathml(sympify(value),printer='presentation')
    str += "</math>"
    return str

print(returnMathML("A"))
```

**test001.py**を実行すると、以下のようにMathMLのコードが出力されます。

```
<math><mi>A</mi></math>
```

**test001.py**の15行目で、渡す引数を"y=a*x**2+b*x+c"に変更して以下のように書き換えて実行してもMathMLのコードが出力されます。

・引数を"y=a*x**2+b*x+c"に変更した場合

```
print(returnMathML("y=a*x**2+b*x+c"))
```

・引数を"y=a*x**2+b*x+c"に変更した場合の実行結果

```
$ python test001.py
<math><mrow><mi>y</mi><mo>=</mo><mrow><mrow><mi>a</mi><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><mo>+</mo><mrow><mi>b</mi><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mi>c</mi></mrow></mrow></math>
```

ただ、文字列に大文字の"S"が加わると、エラーが出てしまいます。

・引数を"S"に変更した場合

```
print(returnMathML("S"))
```

・引数を"S"に変更した場合の実行結果

```
$ python test001.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test001.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(returnMathML("S"))
  File "test001.py", line 11, in returnMathML
    str += mathml(sympify(value),printer='presentation')
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/printing/mathml.py", line 1904, in mathml
    return MathMLPresentationPrinter(settings).doprint(expr)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/printing/mathml.py", line 68, in doprint
    unistr = mathML.toxml()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toxml'
```

これはおそらく、[sympify関数のエイリアスが「S」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55375/python3-6%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-python2-7%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%9F%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8C%E5%8B%95%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F)であるため、名前かぶりが起きているんではないかと思います。

大文字のS以外の、BやCやDといったアルファベットはprintすることが出来ました。また、小文字のsなども大丈夫でした。大文字のSだけがうまく出力できません。

以下のように、面積の"S"を表すのに使用したいです。

```
print(returnMathML("S=abs(a)*(β-α)**3/6"))
```

どうすればこの問題を解決できますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おっしゃるとおり、`S` が `sympify` 関数のエイリアスになっているのが原因です。`sympify()` による string から SymPy オブジェクトへの変換は内部的に `from sympy import *` された状態で行われるので、`"S"` は `Symbol("S")` ではなく `sympify` として扱われます。

この問題を回避するためには、`sympify` のオプショナル引数 `locals` に `"S"` が `Symbol("S")` であると追加した上で呼び出す必要があります。

```py
str += mathml(sympify(value, locals={"S": Symbol("S")}), printer='presentation')
```

このことは [SymPy のドキュメントに書かれており](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=sympify#module-sympy.core.sympify)、こちらには `locals` の設定方法が詳細に書かれています。

ところで[こちらのドキュメント](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html)によると、他にも注意すべき文字があります。一般の文字列に対して `returnMathML` 関数を使うことになるのであれば、これらの対応をどうするか決めなければいけません。たとえば `"O"` はデフォルトでは big-O の O として扱われますが、文脈によってそれで良い場合とそれでは困る場合がありそうです。

> Lastly, it is recommended that you not use `I`, `K`, `S`, `N`, `C`, `O`, or `Q` for variable or symbol names, (中略). You can use the mnemonic `OSINEQ` to remember what Symbols are defined by default in SymPy. Or better yet, always use lowercase letters for Symbol names. Python will not prevent you from overriding default SymPy names or functions, so be careful.

(中略)

> If you want *all* single-letter and Greek-letter variables to be symbols then you can use the clashing-symbols dictionaries that have been defined there as private variables: _clash1 (single-letter variables), _clash2 (the multi-letter Greek names) or _clash (both single and multi-letter names that are defined in abc).
>
> ```py
> >>> from sympy.abc import _clash1
> >>> _clash1
> {'C': C, 'E': E, 'I': I, 'N': N, 'O': O, 'Q': Q, 'S': S}
> >>> sympify('I & Q', _clash1)
> I & Q
> ```